# Private, json file hosting

Tags: json, database, flutter, nosql, hosting

After extensive research and a very thorough comparison I've found that all NoSQL databases uses json to store data, collections and what not.

I have my very own server, and I want it to host a json so that I can save my data right into it instead of relying on a third party provider.

The questions is.....

HOW?

Comment: Saying that all NoSQL databases are just JSON stores is oversimplification. While some do store "documents" of JSON format, e.g. MongoDB stores data in BSON (Binary JSON) format and other types include NoSQL graph databases, key/value databases, tree databases, etc.

Comment: Ahaaaa....ok. I stand corrected!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to have a proper `backend` and `Database` like node,MongoDB,django and more

this might help https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/create-a-rest-api-with-json-server-36da8680136d

Comment: @shinobiatwerk if you find it helpful you may also upvote the answer 
also there are many free json bin hosting website like https://jsonbin.io/about

Comment: aren't these websites limited to how much i can store, read and write into the json file?

Comment: Yes these are limited